# Access Folders in AWS S3 buckets from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have no problem accessing this file:

```
website-001.s3.amazonaws.com/file.jpg
```

How can I access a file in a folder??:

```
website-001.s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/file.jpg
```

In the CloudFront distribution I created a new Origin for `website-001.s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder`. Is this necessary and what else do I have to do to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Your CloudFront URL will look something like d9kg8uxjrbmtcq.cloudfront.net.

If you create the CloudFront distribution pointing to the bucket root (website-001.s3.amazonaws.com), you should be able to access files in myfolder by:

d9kg8uxjrbmtcq.cloudfront.net/myfolder/file.jpg

If you If you create the CloudFront distribution pointing to the folder inside the bucket (website-001.s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder) then you should be able to access files in myfolder by:

d9kg8uxjrbmtcq.cloudfront.net/file.jpg

Comment: Okay thanks! It was a file Permissions issue. I didn't grant read permissions to everyone. It had nothing to do with "Origins" since I only need the one `website-001.s3.amazonaws.com`